# How to implement the Module design pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am reviewing some design patterns in JavaScript. My first design pattern is the module pattern. After researching a bit I built the following example:

```
var CarCostEstimation = (function() {

    //Let's imagine script is getting best price from different api's
    function getBestMotorCost() {

        return 3000;
    }

    function getBestChasisCost() {
        return 1000;
    }

    function getBestWheelsCost() {
        return 400;
    }

    return {
        getEstimatedCost: function() {
            var chasisCost = getBestChasisCost();
            var motorCost = getBestMotorCost();
            var wheelsCost = getBestWheelsCost();

            return chasisCost + motorCost + wheelsCost;
        }
    }

})();

var totalCost = CarCostEstimation.getEstimatedCost();
console.log(totalCost);
```

I have two doubts:

1. If the way I am calling the "private" methods, in my public method is the correct one.
2. If I want to add this `CarCostEstimation` module to another Estimation module, how would it do it?

For point 2:

```
var CostEstimation = (function() {

    var estimationObject;

    function sumDifferentEstimations() {
        estimationObject.getEstimatedCost();
    }

    return {
        addEstimationObjetc: function(object) {
            estimationObject = object
        },

        getTotalCost: function() {
            return sumDifferentEstimations();
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: 1) Yes, that's correct. 2) `var Estimation = { CarCost: CarCostEstimation };`

Comment: @4castle thanks for your comment, what about my update, would that be also an option?

Comment: Yep! The module pattern isn't all that strict. As long as you've got an IIFE and you're only returning the public interface, you're good.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to define your functions. (I'm also using some ES6 syntax)

```
    const CarCostEstimation = function() {
      return {
        getBestMotorCost: () => 3000,
        getBestChasisCost: () => 1000,
        getBestWheelsCost: () => 400,
        getEstimatedCost: function() {
          const chasisCost = this.getBestChasisCost();
          const motorCost  = this.getBestMotorCost();
          const wheelsCost = this.getBestWheelsCost();

          return chasisCost + motorCost + wheelsCost;
        }
      }
    }();

    const totalCost = CarCostEstimation.getEstimatedCost();
    console.log(totalCost);
```

To export your function as a module, you could use the **export** statement from ES6 and import your module using the **import** statement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export